# Understanding output of multivariable integration

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, evaluation

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to integrate this function:

```
K = Function[{x,theta}, 
 ((b - x^3 (d/(Cos[theta])^2 - b/x)^3) (e - 2 b/x)^3/(((b - x^3 (e - 2 b/x)^3) 
 (d/(Cos[theta])^2 - b/x)^3))) Sin[theta]]
```

from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \pi$ and from $x = c$ to $x = \frac{f \cos^2(\theta)}{a + \cos^2(\theta)}$ by executing this command:

```
Integrate[K, {theta, 0, Pi}, {x, c, f((Cos[theta])^2)/(a + (Cos[theta])^2)}].
```

However, when I do this, the output is $\pi  \left(-\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+1}}-1\right) f+c\right)\right) Function\left(\{x,\text{theta}\},\frac{\sin (\text{theta}) \left(\left(e-\frac{2 b}{x}\right)^3 \left(b-x^3 \left(\frac{d}{\cos ^2(\text{theta})}-\frac{b}{x}\right)^3\right)\right)}{\left(b-x^3 \left(e-\frac{2 b}{x}\right)^3\right) \left(\frac{d}{\cos ^2(\text{theta})}-\frac{b}{x}\right)^3}\right)$

What is the meaning of the `Function` part of this result?

The result seems like it's a product of the constants and the function itself, but this doesn't make sense because I clearly specified integration limits.

Comment: Two things. First, `K` is a system variable, so should not be used, and, in general, caution should be used when capitalizing variable names as you can run into conflicts. Second, did you look up [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) in the help? What about [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html)? Do the integrands use `Function`?

Comment: I did read about Integrate, but when I do Integrate[((b - x^3 (d/(Cos[theta])^2 - b/x)^3) (e - 2 b/x)^3/(((b - x^3 (e - 2 b/x)^3) (d/(Cos[theta])^2 - b/x)^3))) Sin[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}, {x, c, f ((Cos[theta])^2)/(a + (Cos[theta])^2)}], like the form of inputs in  the help, it just outputs $\int _0^{\pi }\int _c^{\frac{f \cos ^2(\text{theta})}{a+\cos ^2(\text{theta})}}\frac{\sin (\text{theta}) \left(e-\frac{2 b}{x}\right)^3 \left(\left(b-d x \sec ^2(\text{theta})\right)^3+b\right)}{\left((2 b-e x)^3+b\right) \left(d \sec ^2(\text{theta})-\frac{b}{x}\right)^3}dxd\text{theta}$

Comment: The integral has 20 terms, and each just as nasty as the last. I would have been surprised if _Mathematica_ could have handled it. You're going to have to try substitutions.

Comment: I'm still curious about what the Function part of my original question means, though.  The terms that come before it seem plausible based on the sort of result I expect, and when I do Integrate using other simple Functions (like x^2) as arguments, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Left an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was to long for a comment.

`Function` is a transformation rule, and scoping construct. It allows the user to avoid defining a dependent variable, e.g.

```
Function[{x}, x^2]
```

is equivalent to

```
y[x_] := x^2
```

but in the second case `y` is now associated with the transformation (see [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html)) which is not always desirable, or necessary. Outside of `Function`, or the definition of `y`, `x` has no meaning, so functions like `Integrate` cannot access it, even if the integration variable has the same name. The two *do not* exist in the same *scope*. (This is called lexical scoping, and in a sense, the variables have unique names. `Module` and `With` operate in a similar manner. [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BlocksComparedWithModules.html) does not.) In your integral, you wrote the equivalent of

$$\int^b_a f \, \mathrm{d}x $$

which, strictly speaking, is an abuse of notation. We implicitly assume that $f$ is a function of $x$, but $f$ could just as easily be a constant. In mathematics, we can get away with this because there is usually enough extra information to infer what we mean by $f$. In *Mathematica*, we do not have that luxury, and *Mathematica* interpreted the `Function` as a constant. This occurred even with the presence of `x` and `theta` in it because of their scoped nature.  To be mathematically correct, you are looking for the equivalent of

$$\int^b_a f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, $$

or

```
Integrate[Function[{x}, x^2][x], {x, a, b}]
Integrate[y[x], {x, a, b}]
```

Note, the square brackets. Unless you need it, because of the complexity of the function, the use of `Function` here is overkill, and the *expression* should be used directly

```
Integrate[x^2, {x, a, b}]
```

Comment: Thank you; that's really helpful!